# beamer theme JuanLesPins

Tags: beamer

How can I insert my name, the name of the university, and number in the bottom of the frame?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{Foot}{%
  \insertauthor\hfill\insertinstitute\hfill\insertframenumber}
\author{John Johnson}
\title{The history of ants}
\institute{Stanford Universty}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[Foot]
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}{First frame}{subtitle}
foo
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]